# Is there a name for the "famous" inequality $1+x \leq e^x$?

Tags: probability, analysis, inequality

Is there a name for the "famous" inequality $1+x \leq e^x$? It has many variants depending on how you arrange the terms:

$$1 + x \leq e^x$$
$$e^{-x} -x - 1 \geq 0 $$
$$\ln(1+x) \leq x$$

Et cetera.

Perhaps the simplest mnemonic device is, "$e^x$ lies above its tangent line at the origin." This is at least a geometric instead of arbitrary algebraic expression of the fact.

It comes up in computer science and probability proofs quite frequently. In particular it is a lemma to Chernoff's bounds, and some results regarding the perceptron algorithm and Occam's razor in the PAC learning model. It is very easy to prove by drawing a graph or taking a derivative.

Does it have a name?

More generally I want to ask "why" it's so important, but this is an extremely soft question and I only hope to get used to it in time.

Comment: You mean $1+x\leq e^x$, don't you?

Comment: @ClementC. fixed (by "fixed" I mean "I changed a bunch of signs and maybe it's right now")

Comment: Looks correct now, indeed. As for the name, I don't know of any -- it's a basic convexity inequality, but besides that...

Comment: Notice that $1+x$ is the first order Taylor series (tangent line) for $e^x$ at $x = 0$. Since $e^x$ has positive second derivative, it will always lie above its tangent line.

Comment: @ClementC. you may be either in my class or grading it right now.

Comment: It's similar to Bernoulli's inequality, but I think it's so trivial that there isn't a specific name for it.

Comment: @djechlin (sorry for the flurry of comments) neither TA nor taking classes this semester... Unless you're taking a class back in time (Intro to CLT of last year), pretty unlikely.

Comment: @ClementC. that class, right now, so close :P

Comment: Back to your question: besides being an inequality that holds for all $x$, it is also a tight one: namely, for $x\to 0$ (as is the case where you look at $x$ being "a small  $\varepsilon$,", then the Taylor expansion (first order) gives $e^x = 1+x + o(x)$.

Comment: It's the limit of Bernoulli - $(1+x/n)^n\geq 1+x$, so in the limit $e^x\geq 1+x$. @anomaly

Comment: $(e^x-1-x)$ is also a factor of non-negative integrands that lead to rational approximations to $e$, such as in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2298225/134791

Comment: The inequality seems trivial but is one of the important characterizations of the exponential function. See this question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1776836/72031

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The geometric intuition is certainly that $1+x$ is the tangent line to $e^x$ at $0$, so this amounts to the claim that "$e^x$ lies above its tangent line at the origin." The inequality is tight as $x \rightarrow 0$ in the sense that $e^x = 1 + x + o(x)$.

It's also the limit of the limit of Bernoulli $(1+x/n)^n \geq 1+x$, taking $n \rightarrow \infty$.

(Best answers were in question comments, so assembled here and self-accepted.)

Answer (score 1):

It is so important
because it provides
a nice lower bound
for $e^x$
for 
small $x$.

The inequality
$\log(1+x) \ge 1+x$
for
$0 \le x$
follows easily from
$\log(x)
=\int_1^x \frac{dt}{t}
$.

It is a very special case
of the fact that
the tangent to a curve
at a point
is the best local linear
approximation
to the curve
at that point.

Analytically,
of course,
this is just
the first two terms in the
Taylor series:
$f(x+h)
\approx f(x)+hf'(x)+h^2f''(x)/2+...
$.
With the appropriate
remainder term,
this shows that,
if
$f''(x) \ge 0$,
then
$f(x+h)
\ge f(x)+hf'(x)
$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\log(1+x)\color{red}{\le} 1+x$?