# Representation of $e$ as a descending series

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-function, approximation

I saw on [Wikipedia: List of representations of e](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_representations_of_e) that

$$e=3+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{-1}{k!(k-1)k}$$ 
It was also mentioned that this identity come from consideration on ways to put upper bound of $e$.

Can anyone give me a hint how we can derive this identity? I have tried to look at its *Taylor expansion* but that approach seems to fail miserably.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can derive the following telescoping sum for $k\ge2$:

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{k!}+\frac{1}{k!(k-1)k}
&=\frac{1}{k!}\left(1+\frac{1}{(k-1)k}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{k!}\left(1+\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k}\right)\\
&=\frac{k-1}{kk!}+\frac{1}{(k-1)k!}\\
&=\frac{k-1}{kk!}+\frac{1}{(k-1)k(k-1)!}\\
&=\frac{k-1}{kk!}+\frac{1}{(k-1)(k-1)!}-\frac{1}{k(k-1)!}\\
&=\frac{1}{k!}-\frac{1}{kk!}+\frac{1}{(k-1)(k-1)!}-\frac{1}{k!}\\
&=\frac{1}{(k-1)(k-1)!}-\frac{1}{kk!}
\end{align*}

Hence, if you go back to the original series representation of $e$ as you did:

\begin{align*}
e+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!k(k-1)}
&=2+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}+\frac{1}{k!k(k-1)}\\
&=2+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k-1)(k-1)!}-\frac{1}{kk!}\\
&=2+1-\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{nn!}=3
\end{align*}

Answer (score 14):

As an alternative approach, we have
$$ 3-e=\int_{0}^{1}x(1-x)e^x\,dx \tag{1}$$
by IBP and the RHS of $(1)$ is clearly positive, hence $e<3$.
Since $\int_{0}^{1}x(1-x)\frac{x^k}{k!}\,dx = \frac{1}{k!(k+2)(k+3)}$ we also have
$$ 3-e = \sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{1}{k!(k+2)(k+3)}\tag{2} $$
by termwise integration of a Taylor series.

Comment: Nice approach, but it doesn't look like the sum given right?

Comment: @OussamaBoussif: it is indeed equivalent by simple rearrangements, but your approach by creative telescoping for tackling the original series is superior, so (+1) to you.

Comment: hmm, I think I get it, +1 for the creative use of integration, it's always nice to see different alternatives ^^

Comment: It might be interesting to point out that the approximations $e\approx\frac{19}{7}$ and $e\approx\frac{193}{71}$ come from similar integrals, with $x(1-x)$ being replaced by $x^2(1-x)^2$ and $x^3(1-x)^3$.

Comment: Well, the technique you presented is very powerful then, I don't know how could you come up with such ideas. Your observation is indeed interesting. ^^

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio  What is "IBP"?

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire: Integration By Parts.

Comment: The general form for descending series that follow your pattern, using the Pochhammer symbol, is 
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!(k+2n)_{2n}}$$

Comment: I was wondering what the appropriate generalization was. Do you have a link or reference?

Comment: No, just found it now from the answer and comments. The Pochhammer symbol idea comes from the series for [$\frac{22}{7}-\pi$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1657416/134791)

Comment: For the general form of integrals, https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0601660.pdf

Comment: @OussamaBoussif whenever I see $$\sum \frac{a_n}n$$ I first think $$\int_0^1\sum a_nx^{n-1}\ dx$$

Comment: @Simply Beautiful Art yeah that's right

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio  I had not seen the use of the definite integrals $\int_{0}^{1} x^{n}(1 - x)^{n} e^{x} \mathit{dx}$ to approximate $e$.  May you provide a reference?

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1708366/134791

Answer (score 3):

**An equivalent integral**

Plugging a relationship similar to the one used by Jack D'Aurizio, namely
$$\frac{1}{k!(k-1)k}=\int_0^1 \frac{x^{k-2}(1-x)}{k!} dx$$
into this integral

> $$\int_0^1 \frac{(1-x)(e^x-1-x)}{x^2}dx = 3-e$$

with non-negative integrand in $(0,1)$ that proves $e<3$,
yields the series in the question.

> $$\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{k!(k-1)k}=3-e$$

This relates the series with the [inequality $1+x \leq e^x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1526587/is-there-a-name-for-the-famous-inequality-1x-leq-ex).

**Similar approximations**

This integral is similar to the one used to explain why [$e$ is close to the eighth harmonic number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1605706/why-is-e-close-to-h-8-closer-to-h-8-left1-frac1802-right-and-even).

$$\frac{1}{14} \int_0^1 x^2(1-x)^2(e^x-1-x)dx = e-\frac{761}{280}=e-H_8\approx 0$$

with corresponding series
$$e=\frac{761}{280}+\frac{1}{7}\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{k!(k+3)(k+4)(k+5)}$$

and 
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 (1-x)^2\left(e^x-1-x-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)dx = e-\frac{163}{60}$$

used to explain the observation by Lucian that [$2\pi+e$ is close to $9$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1711437/an-integral-for-2-pie-9).

**Another series for $3-e$**

Yet another series to prove $e<3$ is related to the integer sequence http://oeis.org/A165457.

$$\frac{1}{e}=\frac{1}{3}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k+1)!(2k+3)}$$